# Page Flip Animation For SKTexture?

Tags: ios, swift, sktexture

Is there any way I could animate an `SKTexture` (lets say its a red square), so that is "peels" from the left to the right like a page, revealing another `SKTexture` underneath (lets say a blue square)?

Example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg04wfnDpiQ

Except it would only left to right, not following the finger.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use UIPageController for this purpose its very easy in iOS unlike Android. You can search for UIPageController tutorial on web. 
Use this for page animation

self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

on the place of

self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];